# is_block_type_valid error when invoking class constructor from dll

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

I have built a DLL and exported some members from a class via the `__declspec(dllexport)` keyword. I'm mainly just trying to export a constructor from my class.

I then get a handle on the DLL which is successful.

Next, I can get the DLL export of the constructor by using the DLL handle and the process name.

I receive the export and it is not null, so it looks like it can find it.
The problem is that when I invoke the exported constructor function, I receive an error which says:

`Expression: is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)`

The constructor isn't anything special, just setting up some variables.

I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here in order to find out what is wrong.

Sorry the problem, that I found was that I cannot export std::stringstream members into the DLL. For some reason, if I export a class with this member, I get that error.

This throws the error:

```
/*****************************
* Testing
*****************************/
class DLL_API test_sup_class: public std::enable_shared_from_this<test_sup_class>
{
public:
    test_sup_class();

    virtual int initialize() = 0;

    static int test_sup_function();

public:

    //! Should draw debug ?
    bool                                b_draw_debug;

    //! Should draw debug ?
    bool                                b_debug_draw_limits;

public:
    std::shared_ptr<ik_solver_impl> impl;

    //! Debug strings printed from the solver
    std::stringstream                   str;

    //! Joint data for the solver
    std::shared_ptr<ik_joint_data>      joint_data;

    //! Pointer to the BIK solver
    std::shared_ptr<test_class>         test_class_ptr;


};
```

Comment: It's hard to provide any useful advice without seeing how you are using this constructor.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, and where did you encounter problems (__including__ code). Check [\[SO\]: How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [\[SO\]: mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more asking related details.

Comment: I have edited the question.. Looks like the culprit was including std::stringstream in the class. I think I have to make an interface for it?

Comment: Hmmm at 2nd look, are you trying to instantiate an __abstract__ (having at least one _pure virtual_ method (`initialize`)) class? 2nd: Why are you getting the constructor "_by using the DLL handle and the process name_" (whatever _process name_ would mean, maybe `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress`)? Why don't just include the header?